# SSAS - How to connect a Time Dimension to a DateTime attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssas, olap-cube

I created a Time Dimension by using SSAS Dimension Wizard.
It works well, I can browse it easily.

[image]

However, I would like to connect this dimension to a "createdAt" attribute of type DateTime from my fact table.

This is an extract of my FactTable
[image]

Then, I linked the dimension to the fact table :
[image]

I don't understand how to process to connect the new dimension table to the attribute.
Each time I process my cube I get this error :

```
Erreurs dans le moteur de stockage OLAP : Clé d'attribut introuvable lors du traitement de : Table : 'dbo_Sale', Colonne : 'createdAt', Valeur : '01/01/2014 08:58:17'. L'attribut est 'Date'.
```

It seems an Attribute Key is missing during the process.
Any idea ? Should I convert type createdAt attribute to another format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would truncate the time portion of your createdAt column, eg by using a double CAST function e.g.

`CAST ( CAST ( createdAt AS DATE ) AS DATETIME ) AS createdAt`

Then the values should match your Dimension Keys.

Comment: Where to write that expression??

Answer (score 2):

1. In the data source view, right click the table with 'createdAt'
   column and click "New Named Calculation".
2. Give your column a name. I will call it here createdAtDate. Add the following in the Expression:

   cast(createdAt as date)
3. In the dimension usage, set the relationship as Regular and use the new defined calculated column createdAtDate instead of createdAt.